# In YouTube Live Stream, audio is pitched too high

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, audio, youtube-live

My channel does weekly live streams, but often the audio is pitched too high and we sound like chipmunks. It did sound normal one time, so it's possible, but I'm not exactly sure what the problem is. I've followed all the YouTube guidelines for streaming, so I need some help troubleshooting.

For reference, here's the video that worked: https://youtu.be/0W9ZEDsvzmA
And here's a video with chipmunk sound: https://youtu.be/B1oYoDeLusQ

We have a Zoom H4N Pro external mic and for now we are using the native webcam for video, and use OBS to manage the feed. We are in China, so we have to use a VPN to access YouTube.

**OBS Settings**
OUTPUT
Audio bitrate: 128
Enable Advanced encoder settings CHECKED
Enforce streaming service bitrate limits CHECkED

AUDIO
Sample rate: 44.1khz
channels: stereo

**Zoom** is recording at sample rate: 44.1khz.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there additional information I should be checking?

The time it worked, we actually were recording at 48kHz, so I'll try that this weekend. But YouTube says that the sample rate should be 44.1.

Comment: could be video framerate issue or even resolution issue (https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/audio-pitch-is-lowered-in-youtube-stream.36414/) but simple audio tuning program where you can set a pitch for output should resolve your issue

Comment: I'm not entirely sure it belongs here, as it seems like it could be a hardware issue.  I'm inclined to leave it here for the time being, but if it's really related to the recording itself, it may be more appropriate on [SU].